# Keep one fragment with semi transparent background on the top layer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to do this :
|fragment menu (semi-transparent)| body (covered all the screen width) |

I have a menu in a fragment on the left of the screen and when I click on a menu button, I want open a new fragment in the body (body's size = screen's size). And I want that fragment menu must be still visible with a semi-trasnsparent background.

This is my xml layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_image"
    >

    <fragment android:name="com.example.Principal_Menu"
              android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
              android:layout_width="150dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/body_container"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I replace or add the fragment in the body_container the menu_fragment disappears :(
I hope was clear and I'm sorry to ask many questions.

Comment: yes it should, because you have replaced the old one with a new one, and also the body container layout is fill parent so it will, what do you want to happen that the menu always stays on top? or infront of the body

Comment: Hi @Elltz thanks to the answer ! I would want that menu with a semi-transparent background stays in front of the body and that through  the semi-transparent background we can also see the part of the body under menu . I have tried in different ways but I can't ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the transparent menu to be infront of the `body_container` then re-construct your xml like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" 
android:background="@drawable/background_image" >

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">    

  <FrameLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/body_container"
     android:orientation="vertical">

   </FrameLayout>

  <fragment android:name="com.example.Principal_Menu"
          android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The logic here is FrameLayout stacks Views on top of Views so with this layout the Fragment in the body_container will be behind the menu Fragment and if you want the Fragment in the body_container to be infront you can either use this code on the Fragment `getView().bringToFront();` or call this code `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(the_menu_fragment).commit();`

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much ! I will try your code and I let update you. I only read the code, but why gravity center is set to horizontal for the menu_fragment ? Have I to set it in this way also if I want that menu_fragment still on the left ?

Comment: Oh sorry it was early :D I suppose that for menu fragment I have to develop a layout where the part of it is total transparent and with the button semi-transparent ?

Comment: oh sorry about that Sir, change the gravity to `android:layout_gravity="top|left"`, i forgot that about your question, to your second comment yeah if it suit your needs, but is your menu `Fragment` a `Fragment` or a `DialogFragment` ?

Comment: okay then you can set the background of the `getView()` to transparent so the rest of the `View` will lie on nothing, `getView()`.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent));` mind you, use `setBackground` for api 16+ and `setBackgroundDrawable` for api 16- im i lucid for you?@aeroxr1

Comment: I develop for SDK > 18 :) So i can set the background color in the xml of the fragment menu, right ? :)

Comment: yes you easily can Sir, Thank you friend :) that's nice to know @aeroxr1